# 'homestead up' throwing error (Shell provisioner `args`) during installation

Tags: php, laravel, installation, vagrant, homestead

After following the [laravel installation guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) when i run `homestead up` I get the error message:

```
$ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

My Homestead.yaml file is configured like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Developer/PHP
      to: /home/vagrant/php

sites:
    - map: rmm.app
      to: /home/vagrant/php/rmm/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - name: homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Comment: I'm installing on my MacBook so Mac OSX

Comment: The happens when your homestead.yaml file is not properly configure, ensure you use absolute paths,e.g is this pointing to the right path that exists? ~/Developer/PHP

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by absolute paths?

Comment: Solution worked perfectly, thank you so much! I forgot to respond because I've hit a new possibly unrelated error.

Comment: Ok. Good. Kindly accept my answer below, so that this can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this in your Homestead.yaml configuration

```
 databases: 
   - name: homestead
```

to

```
databases: 
   - homestead
```

and then try running homestead up once more.
Also ensure your paths in Homestead.yaml configuration are correct